# Stored Procedure never completes execution - Oracle

Tags: loops, random, oracle11g, sql-delete

I have table, which is having 26 columns and is 1TB in size. I am trying to use the following stored procedure to delete the records from this table randomly:

```
declare cnt number;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN 1 .. 2 LOOP
         SELECT RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID into cnt FROM MV_RUN_VER_IES SAMPLE (0.00091) WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
         DELETE FROM MV_RUN_VER_IES WHERE RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID = cnt;
    END LOOP;
    commit;
END;
/
```

But the issue is the above loop just goes into infinite execution loop and never completes. I am not sure what I am trying to do wrong here. The reason I say that, when I execute this SQL:

```
SELECT RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID FROM MV_RUN_VER_IES SAMPLE (0.00091) WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
```

It executes in fraction of a second. Also the column **RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID** is a primary key column in the table.

**UPDATE:**

Not sure why, but this script is doing the work without any issues:

```
VARIABLE cnt integer;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN 1 .. 4000 LOOP
         SELECT RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID into :cnt FROM MV_RUN_VER_IES SAMPLE (0.00091) WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
         DELETE FROM "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_IES" WHERE "RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID" = :cnt;
    END LOOP;
    commit;
END;
```

Comment: First you'll want to find out exactly which statement or line is causing the problems.  To do this, run the procedure, and check `select * from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`.  Do you see the `SELECT` or the `DELETE`?

Comment: @JonHeller Thanks for your comment. I see `DELETE` statement.

Comment: A DELETE on a primary key shouldn't take long.  That implies it's waiting on a lock.  Perhaps some other process has modified the same rows but didn't commit.  To verify this, try to find the session and see if someone is blocking it: `select blocking_session, gv$session from gv$session;`.  Then find the blocking session like this: `select * from gv$session where sid = <blocking_session_from_above>;`.

Answer (score 0):

please get the actual value of the cnt,

the watch the execution plan(do not real execute the sql)

you could use explain plan for

then query select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());

for the execution plan.
if the execution plan really shows primay key

please really execute the sql,

then query v$session_wait for the wait event for this session

Comment: can you please tell me how can I get the value of **cnt**. And yes the execution plan does primary key. And I am sorry, but I cannot point anything peculiar from the **v$session_wait** view.

Comment: all i am refered is about the delete sql, NOT the select